# Dynamic Slideshow

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms, slideshow

My client need to have a dynamic slideshow but he wants his images protected. so obviously I can't use a JQuery slideshow :S .. he don't mind a screenshot because the slideshow won't be that big so the resolution won't be the same.

Now I'm thinking about a dynamic flash player .. but is it possible to have such a thing ?
other options are also welcome =)

Comment: what about adding a watermark to the images, dynamically, so you don't have to introduce flash?

Comment: The client is so crazy about the pictures .. so he doesn't think watermark only would be enough .. but if you don't mind, how would I add dynamically a watermark !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use flash with XML there are various slideshow example on internet one I found

http://www.flabell.com/flash/XML-Image-Slideshow-40

Comment: Yeah that's great. I found the same one by luck while waiting for an answer. It's the first time to even hear about such a thing like XML Flash! .. anyway all I have to do is to provide an upload code for my client and some code to parse the XML file and add a new line for the new image right ? .. if you've used it before a C# sample for parsing the XML would be great =) .. Thanks Govind +1

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Jquery slideshow and just add the following function:

to target just the image files:

```
$('img').bind("contextmenu mousedown",function(){          
  return false;
});
```

or to target the whole site:

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu mousedown",function(){          
  return false;
});
```